# Split instead of showing errors when opening file from quickfix

Tags: quickfix

Is it possible to get behaviour like `switchbuf=split`, but only on error?

I don't want tons of windows that comes with using `switchbuf=split`, but I don't want to see errors like "E37: No write since last change" and "E36: Not enough room".

Is it possible to configure vim to open files from the quickfix in:

1. existing window containing buffer (`switchbuf=useopen`)
2. last used window  (`switchbuf=uselast`)
3. if error, split (??)

So it never shows these errors during buffer switch.

I'd previously used [this code](https://github.com/idbrii/vim-fixquick/blob/master/autoload/fixquick/window.vim#L124-L138) mapped to `<CR>` but found it didn't always jump to the correct file.